# Working with multiple solutions and file references in the nuget / .NET Core era

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, asp.net-core, visual-studio-debugging, .net-core

**Background**

I'm working on a large application consisting of tens of solutions, each containing a number of projects. References between projects in a solution are done using project references. References between projects in other solutions use file references to a common shared "bin" directory. We do this by:

1. Building the solutions in the correct order (we have our own custom way of ensuring this)
2. Configuring the output location of all class library assemblies to build into a shared "bin" directory
3. Referencing these class library assemblies using file references from the projects that depend on them

Everything is in one big repository and is branched/versioned together.

This works well for us and allows us to easily reference code between solutions. It is also relatively painless to make a code change in a dependent solution, rebuild it, then immediately have that change available to the solution that depends on it. For example, a utility library that's used by a number of applications.

**The problem/question**

We're currently looking to add a new ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC1 project/solution (using .NET Framework 4.6.1, not .NET Core) and need to reference assemblies outside of the ASP.NET Core project's solution.

If we add a file reference from an ASP.NET Core project to an assembly in the shared "bin" directory it appears to work but what happens is that the .dll is copied into a lib directory in the root of the ASP.NET Core project's solution directory. Because this file is a copy, and has no link back to the original location, it means that any subsequent changes to the assembly won't be picked up. Unless the reference is removed and re-added. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but this lib and wrap directory approach doesn't work for our use case.

Given that nuget seems to be the preferred way of adding references, we've also tried this approach. We have a build script which creates a nuget package for each of the assemblies in the shared "bin" directory and stores them in a directory at the root of the repository, I can now reference these assemblies as nuget packages, and after a bit of rebuilding/repackaging the changes are then picked up by the dependent projects. Because the whole repository is "versioned" together there's no need to any versioning of the assemblies/packages - everything is just on 1.0.0. This goes against the point of nuget somewhat but it's so ingrained into the architecture of our application it wouldn't be easy to change.

Whilst the nuget approach feels a bit awkward, it does appear to work. However, the pdb files are no longer found/used by the debugger, even though they're included in the nuget package. This is a big loss in productivity.

- **Are we misunderstanding how the "lib and wrap" approach works?**
- **Is it possible to get file referenced nuget packages to be debuggable?**
- **Is there an alternative approach that would be more like what we used to do?**

Comment: Sounds like you need your own nuget feed. It can be as simple as a network share. You should know that ASP.NET Core Class LIbraries (called "Class Library (package)" in Visual Studio) generate nuget packages, not just plain dll like the legacy one. You'd basically want to build each of these class libraries and put them in a network share or a nuget server (there is an library to implement your own nuget server) and add this nuget feed (or folder) in your NuGet.config as another source. Then whenever you build or restore your project, they will fetch the packages form there

Comment: @Tseng Setting up a nuget feed is overkill when you're working locally with multiple projects that are changing rapidly and want to be productive. It's the correct solution for many cases, just not ours.

Comment: If you really have so many solutions with so many project it does make sense. At such size a build server is almost mandatory and it can be configured to create the packages and push it to the location where the feed is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are we misunderstanding how the "lib and wrap" approach works?

The "lib and wrap" is not actually fully-fledged. I think **RC2** is promising to have `.csproj` and `xproj`  projects working together. As of now, you can look @ how the [EF project](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework) does this.

> Is it possible to get file referenced nuget packages to be debuggable?

With **ASP.NET Core 1.0**, you can reference projects outside of your current solution via the `project.json` as `dependencies`. As you are well aware, what you're probably missing is that with those very references you can have them be resolved from your local *file system* instead of *DNX*.

Using the `global.json` in the solution you can add project directories that **Visual Studio** will use to look for before attempting to resolve via **NuGet / DNX**.

**Example**

```
{
  "projects": [
    "src",
    "test",
    "../Some.Other.Project/src", // Will look here for projects
    "../../Some.External.Project/src" // Will look here for projects
  ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1"
  }
}
```

The `src` and `test` directories are the default directories in which the standard templates place source projects and test projects.

Then, if you're taking a dependency on either of the projects called out in the `global.json` it will pull those projects into the solution explorer and treat them almost like "virtual projects", but you can still actually be able to debug (and step into them) and change them and they are tracked as part of source control.

> Is there an alternative approach that would be more like what we used to do?

I described what you should be doing above, take the `global.json` approach.

Comment: Thanks for the global.json suggestion - that seems to be working well. The debugging is still a bit sketchy but a combination of ReSharper and dotPeek running as a symbol server is working well enough for now.

Comment: I spoke too soon, it was only working because I hadn't cleaned up the old nuget packages I'd been trying. I've had to use dnu wrap to create project.json files for all the project I want to reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your solutions clean and independent from each other, the recommended way is adding the dependencies as NuGet packages. However, when working on multiple solutions and rebuilding them frequently, you will face an annoying obstacle: the NuGet package cache. Essentially, what you need is to step the version number of your projects every time you make some modifications so that dependent projects in different solutions can get the update. For this, I've written a simple dotnet tool that you can use to step the revision number of the project on every build:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-bump

Works like a charm, you just have to update the NuGet packages in the referencing projects. Naturally, when publishing a project, you would step the major/minor/patch number and set the revision back to 0.